# C++ missing information in compiler error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a Visual C++ 2013 project but the compiler is throwing this mysterious error:

`Error  1   error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.`

It does not tell me which class that is missing a hash, nor does it tell me in which file the error occurs. Rather, it links me to a line in the file `xstdef` which seem to be one of the compiler's libraries.

How can such critical information have been left out of the error message and how do I go about figuring out which class that is the perpetrator?

Comment: Well... find the file that's using a map-like object.

Comment: Is that the entire error message? (Look in the Output tab, the error list is rubbish.) Start with examining what you're putting into your `std::unordered_map`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Output tab, it will sometimes list more lines of code (e.g. template instance generated from file/line.)  This can help you find the real problem - it will usually be from somewhere trying to USE the class, and not point directly to the class definition.

If you've made recent changes, you can try bisecting or stashing to find the change that introduced the error.